# Strange name(s) in Windows Permission Settings for a registry key

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-registry

I was following [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2018/12/29/windows-10-user-profile-service-event-id-1534-warnings/) article to try to remove a particular warning. The keys cannot be removed without changing the permissions and that's when I came across this.

[image]

Google tells me it's German. However, I purchased the laptop in Canada, new, from Dell. Apart from US I do not have any other languages enabled on windows.

I have never worked with or installed anything related to the German language. Is it just a fluke?

Comment: So which account are you asking about?  You have censored all the profile names, even the account, that no longer exists.

Comment: He’s asking about the “Applies to” column, which is indeed in German.

Comment: Which registry key might be helpful.

Comment: This isn't normal, and might indicate that your computer was used by a German-speaker before being sold to you. Are you sure that you didn't buy a reconditioned computer?

Comment: The unknown account might be to blame, but I cannot determine anything, because of the edits done to the screenshot.  I would try and change the ownership of the registry key, to a different user, then change it back.

Comment: @Moab It's this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileNotification`

Comment: @harrymc That's possible. However I distinctly remember going through the usual steps of booting a new computer where Windows asks things about the initial setup.

Comment: @Ramhound It looked like a GUID. I'll post the unblurred version once I get home.

Comment: Instead of submitting comments, just update your question, with the relevant information.